# VBA basic commands/ syntax

Tags: vba, excel, module

I am currently trying to write a program which can facilitate the transfer of specific information from one Excel workbook to another.

Currently I am only able to transfer information from a single preselected (hard coded into the module) cell to another workbook.

I have a couple of questions regarding the VBA commands which will help me code this more efficiently.

Firstly, what are the types of loops in VBA and can someone quickly go over how they are used?

Secondly, is there a way for the module for work off of a cell the USER manually selects with the mouse? As in the user manually clicks a cell on the screen and the program runs based off of the location of that cell?

Lastly, what is the function which would let me select adjacent cells from the currently selected position?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For information: The answers to your questions are easily found by using a Google search. Generally here its more of a "Help me find out where my code is not working" and not a "give me a code for". Having said that I still answered your question to the best of my ability. maybe post another question or edit your question to include some code from your current Macro and give an explanation where you not sure what to do, this way people can comment or assist.

Comment: For sure. Sorry I found the website today and got all excited and started spamming questions. Thank you for spending some time to help me out! :)

Comment: No problem, its all about learning friend. Just remember to upvote and tick the answer you found to your question. Enjoy the site!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few `Loop` statements:

---

```
a = 10
c = 1
Do While c < a
  'somescript
  c = c + 1
Loop
```

---

```
a = 10
c = 1
While c < a
  'some script
  c = c + 1
Wend
```

---

```
c = 1     
Do Until c = 10
  'some script
  c = c + 1
Loop
```

---

```
For Each Paragraph In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
        'some script
Next Paragraph
```

---

```
For i = 0 To 100
    'some script
Next i
```

---

A description can be found [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html). and it will depend on your application as to what loop you want to use.

To execute a Marco from a cell you would use the a Sub in the Microsoft Excel Objects - Sheet in your Project and then use one of the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

To use the data from an adjacent cell you would use `Offset`, example below:

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    'cell B3 is set to the rng
    Set rng = Cells(2, 3)
    'cell B4 is set to the rng2
    Set rng2 = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    'cell B4 will be activated
    rng2.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your in depth explanation!